# MATLAB curve fitting - least squares method - wrong “fit” using high degrees

Tags: matlab, regression, least-squares

Anyone here that could help me with the following problem?
The following code calculates the best polynomial fit to a given data-set, that is; a polynomial of a specified degree.

Unfortunately, whatever the data-set may be, usually at degree 6 or higher, MATLAB gets a totally wrong fit.  Usually the fit curves totally away from the data in a sort of exponantial-looking-manner downwards.  (see the example: degree = 8).

```
x=[1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5] % experimental x-values
y=[4.3 6.2 10.1 13.5 19.8 22.6 24.7 29.2] % experimental y-values

degree=8; % specify the degree
A = zeros(length(x),degree);
for exponent=0:degree;
for data=1:length(x);
   A(data,exponent+1)=x(data).^exponent; % create matrix A
end;
end;

a=inv((transpose(A)*A))*transpose(A)*y'; % a are the coëfficients of the polynom
a=flipud(a);
fitpolynoom=polyval(a,x);
error=sum((y-fitpolynoom).^2); % calculates the fit-error using the least-squares method
fitpolynoom=polyval(a,x);

figure;
plot(x,y,'black*',x,fitpolynoom,'g-');

error % displays the value of the fit-error in the Matlab command window
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Degree 8 - wrong MATLAB polynomial curve fitting]

Comment: Have you tried QR decomposition for solving for the coefficients? Your method is numerically not very stable. I recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29

Comment: I haven't. I am not aware of a method to do this. Can you give me any advice on how to implement this? Or perhaps any theoretical explanation on why this could solve or explain the issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: For stability one often normalizes the data by subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation prior to fitting. These terms are then put back in why evaluating the polynomial to get back to the original scale and range. You can always compare your results against `polyfit` to make sure you are getting what you are supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

With the least squares method you try to 'solve' an system of linear equations $Ax = b$ for $x$, but if $A$ is not square (thats why you cannot solve exactly) the least square approach is $A^tAx = A^tb$. If you solve this straight forward this can generate huge numericl errors (everything is finde though if you solve it *exactly*, but Matlab can't do that.). That's why one normally uses the qr decomposition $A=QR$ where $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is a upper triangular matrix, so you can solve the least square problem by $Ax = QRx = b$ Since $Q$ is orthonormal you can solve this by $x = R^{-1} Q^t b$. I just applied it to your code and it seems to work very well:
[image: plot]

Another thing to consider is that polynomials of 'high' degrees tend to oscilate very much even if the points are almost linear. A rule of thumb is that you should expect heavy oscilations f everythiing above degree 7 or 9.

```
%%
x=[1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5] % experimental x-values
y=[4.3 6.2 10.1 13.5 19.8 22.6 24.7 29.2] % experimental y-values

degree=8; % specify the degree
A = zeros(length(x),degree);
for exponent=0:degree;
for data=1:length(x);
   A(data,exponent+1)=x(data).^exponent; % create matrix A
end;
end;
[q,r] = qr(A);
a=r \ q'*y'; % a are the coëfficients of the polynom
a=flipud(a);

fitpolynoom=polyval(a,x);
error=sum((y-fitpolynoom).^2); % calculates the fit-error using the least-squares method
xx = min(x):0.01:max(x);
fitpolynoom=polyval(a,xx);

figure;
plot(x,y,'black*',xx,fitpolynoom,'g-');

error % displays the value of the fit-error in the Matlab command window
```

Comment: Your theory is congruent with my issue! Great implementation into my code, many thanks for the help and explanation.

Comment: I am glad I could help you! I didn't find anything useful right away for the theory, perhaps you might read: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs3220-s12/notes/lec10.pdf

The 'problem' of the normals equation you first used is that if the points are almost linearly dependent, you cannot invert the matrix very accurately (a small rounding error can result in a huge total error, imagine calculating the intersection of two almost parallel lines, a small error can lead to a huge difference).

Comment: Interesting, somebody else gave a solution to the problem using a different approach:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508361/matlab-curve-fitting-least-squares-method-wrong-fit-using-high-degrees

The fit-errors differ in both approaches however, I wonder which one of them are "most realistic"?

Perhaps one of them would also have less dramatic oscillating peaks (which seem to occur mostly at the last (or first) elements of the data vectors, I wonder why and further more: can these oscillations not be avoided or averaged out)?

Comment: When I run the program, the error as you defined is is at $2.9\cdot 10^{-20}$ which is better than you could expect, since the default floating point numbers in matlab have a precision of around $10^{-16}$, so you can consider anything lower than $eps$ basically as zero. The idea that the guy at Stackoverflow provided, is that it is numerically much more stalbe to use the $\ $ operator instead of actually inverting the the whole matrix. $\ $ is just calculating a $LR$-decomposition and solving throu substitution/backsubstitution, while $inv$ inverts the whole matrix, which is much less stable.

Comment: Both solutions do provide the same exact same polynomial since they both use the exact same method. Apart from some rounding errors that influenced it differently. But if you do have such a bad condition as you have here (points almost linear dependent) then even the $\ $ operator will give you worse results than the $QR$ decomposition. Also note that if you want an unique polynomial, you should use a $7$-th degree, which has $8$ degrees of freedom, so it is uniquely defined by $8$ points.

Comment: I ran the 3 solutions for different degrees, and also considered creating A as a sparse matrix using A= **sparse(** zeros(leng.. @flawr means using the QR decomposition mentioned above. §Juho means not inverting the matrix (See [Stackoverflow]). ---
**<Degree 5>** Same for all solutions = _1.3170_ --- **<Degree 7>** Original= _4.5*10^-9_ | Original(sparse)= _6.1*10^-5_ | @flawr= _6.4*10^-19_ | @flawr(sparse)= _8.4*10^-19_ | §Juho= _7.1*10^-10_ | §Juho(sparse)= _4.5*10^-9_ --- **<Degree 9>** @flawr= _2.7*10^-19_ | @flawr(sparse)= _1.8*10^-19_ | §Juho= _1.9*10^-15_ | §Juho(sparse)= _8.2*10^-14_

Comment: You guess the factorization mentioned on [John D. Cook's blog](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) is a LR-decomposition? I have found no clues about this in his article.

Do you suggest that my matrix A would also be full of 0's? In that sense I could understand why inverting would generate more data.

Comment: Well the matlab operator $\$ ('backslash' solver) is a pretty sophisticated tool that never inverts an matrix and then multplies, but rather first analyzes the matrix and then performs an algorithm that is best suited for the problem. If you have a full non symmetrical matrix I think it will be a LR-decomposition with pivoting if the size allows that. Keep in mind that different techniques that seem to perform the same from a mathematical view, can have totally different numerical properties. I recommend taking lectures/reading about numerical matrix algorithms. (Numerical linear algebra).

Comment: PS: Here is a overview how the backslash solver works: http://www.maths.lth.se/na/courses/NUM115/NUM115-11/backslash.html and some notes on 'inv' (even the guys at mathworks do not recommend using it from a numerical standpoint) http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html

Answer (score 1):

Nooo, not for loops in Matlab. It is super slow. Here is how you do it.

```
x=[1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5] % experimental x-values
y=[4.3 6.2 10.1 13.5 19.8 22.6 24.7 29.2] % experimental y-values
xs = linspace(min(x),max(x),128)';
Phi=x'.^[0:8];
lhs = Phi'*Phi;
rhs = Phi'*y';   
c=lhs\rhs;
figure(1); close(1);figure(1); plot(x',y','x','linewidth',2);
hold on; plot(xs,xs.^[0:8]*c,'linewidth',2);
```

We did not even need to use a regularization here, but usually that would be advisable for high order polynomial fittings. A primitive regularizer would be achieved by adding for example lhs = lhs + epsilon*eye(size(lhs));

If we instead of solving the normal equations solve lhs = Phi; rhs = y'; we get a solution that looks more like @flawr s above.

[image]